# Python - no clear XML - tags and values mixed

Tags: python, xml, parsing

In the following section, while parsing I am getting correct printing for title, price but not for book id.  Thank you all in advance.

The following tries to read book id, title, price an print them 
example structure of the booksExample.xml file

```
<book id="bk101">
  <author>F-NAME, L-NAME</author>
  <title>BOOK'S TITLE</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>ANALYTICAL INFORMATION ABOUT IT.</description>
</book>
```

Code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
doc = parse('booksExample.xml')

for book in doc.findall('book'):
   id = book.findtext('id')
   title = book.findtext('title')
   price = book.findtext('price')
   print id, title, price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is an attribute of the book element so you have to use `book.get('id')`, not `book.findtext('id')`

**parse.py:**

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
doc = parse('booksExample.xml')

for book in doc.findall('book'):
   id = book.get('id')
   title = book.findtext('title')
   price = book.findtext('price')
   print id, title, price
```

Just for reference, using the following as `booksExample.xml`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx

**output:**

```
(parsexml)macbook:parsexml joeyoung$ python parse.py 
bk101 XML Developer's Guide 44.95
bk102 Midnight Rain 5.95
bk103 Maeve Ascendant 5.95
bk104 Oberon's Legacy 5.95
bk105 The Sundered Grail 5.95
bk106 Lover Birds 4.95
bk107 Splish Splash 4.95
bk108 Creepy Crawlies 4.95
bk109 Paradox Lost 6.95
bk110 Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible 36.95
bk111 MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide 36.95
bk112 Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide 49.95
```

Comment: That was exactly the clarification I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Cool. You can accept the answer if it was helpful.  Cheers.